# My Ubuntu used to go fast, recently it started going slow, any helpful tips?

Tags: download-speed

Okay, it used to go fast, just like it should, but yesterday, everything started to slow drastically. It's gotten to the point I can't even watch an entire episode of something on Hulu without the page crashing. Has this happened to anyone before? No, I haven't installed anything new recently, and after it slowed down, I even uninstalled unnecessary items such as Wine and Perl. It's gotten even slower since then, but when I'm off for a while and then get back on, it goes at least a little faster for awhile, but not long enough to do much.

Should I just wait longer between uses, or is this an actual problem I should fix?

Note: Disregard the tag, I couldn't find one that really fit.

It's in Ubuntu 14.04

Probably is, but I'm not 100% sure on the hardware, was bought for my birthday and I wasn't really told the Hardware Specs. (I can try to find the name of the model and look it up, but as of now that's all the information I have). And I haven't tried booting an old kernel, though that might be one of my next courses that I take. The RAM and the rest of it, not that I know of.

Comment: show your hardware configuration

Comment: slow is usually releated to hardware. does it help to boot an old kernel ? is your hard drive full? something using your ram ?

Comment: Okay, don't really want to edit again, but, to the hard drive being full question: no it's not full. I have plenty of space.

Comment: first off
@edwardtorvalds http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c04278796&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en there's the specs

Comment: @Parto looking at the answer now, yeah, it's pretty well what i was asking, i just hadn't seen it when i looked... thanks!

Comment: you can use light weight desktop like KDE-PLASMA WORKSPACE, you will find it in software center. i saw you processor, on this type of processor unity will be slow. unity is resource eater, so try kde